# Comunicação Serial e Divisão de Array com Virgula

Tags: python, serial, conversão

Olá, Boa Noite, hoje me surgiu outro problema, lendo dados gerados por sensores do arduino, consegui imprimi-los e salva-los em uma array, porém para realmente ficar bom, necessito quebrar as duas colunas separadas, como no exemplo

```
292.00,2436.00

292.00,2467.00

293.00,2498.00
```

Porém não posso criar um arquivo .CSV, para salvar e depois pega-lo denovo apenas pra converter em duas array, queria fazer isso no próprio código do python

```
import serial 
import time
import numpy as np

entrada = serial.Serial('COM4', 4800)

tempo_leitura = time.time() + 5 # Contador de 5 segundos
geral = 0

def leituraSerial():
    while(time.time() < tempo_leitura):
        np.geral = entrada.readline().decode()
        print(np.geral)
        time.sleep(0.01)


def conversorSerial():
    #único jeito que sei fazer é a partir de loadtxt(), que não creio ser o caso, tentei diversas maneiras, porém não nenhuma obteve sucesso. Outra dúvida é o retorno do .decode() é uma string correto?
```

Comment: Como assim quebrar as duas colunas separadas? Os valores vem juntos pela serial e você precisa separá-los?

Answer (score 1):

Use o método **split()** para quebrar a *string* que você recebe pela serial e use o retorno para alimentar as variáveis:

```
>>> valor="292.00,2436.00"
>>> (v1, v2) = valor.split(",")
>>> v1
>>> '292.00'
```

Claro que elas virão como *string*, então você pode criar uma função para cuidar de separar e converter os valores:

```
>>> def separa(v):
...     (v1, v2) = v.split(",")
...     return float(v1),float(v2)
... 
>>> (v1,v2) = separa(valor)
>>> v1
292.0
>>> v2
2436.0
```

Comment: Sua solução parece resolver o problema, porém percebi em testes que fiz, que o np.geral não recebe todas as leituras, somente a última.